# "Looped" elements in row

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to accomplish "looped" row of elements like this:

[image: Example of looped elements]

This row should work like carousel, I mean if we click "Next" button then current element is changed and moved to the center of the row (e.x. If on the screenshot above it's showed that the current element is "One" and after click on "Next" button it will change on "Two" and "Two" will be centered and "One" will be pushed back) and I want to make this row (graphically?) as looped row where beggining and the end of the row are "connected". I have no idea if in CSS is some trick to "curve" div or something or it should be done in JS.

I have array of elements in JS:

```
const elements = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"];
```

And row initialized with the array in HTML:

```
<div id="loopedRow">
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Two</span>
  <span>Three</span>
  <span>Four</span>
  <span>Five</span>
  <span>Six</span>
  <span>Seven</span>
  <span>Eight</span>
  <span>Nine</span>
  <span>Ten</span>
</div>
```

Could someone point me a direction where to look for something like this? I'll be grateful.

Comment: Your question is missing essential information. Please make some research and complete your question. Also please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What essential information? I don't have more information

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying accomplish based on your description

Comment: You want to do this with vanilla JavaScript or you are open to using some weight light library?

Comment: At the moment I am open for ideas :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this helpful or not. Inside `callXTimes` put your actual display logic.

```js
const elements = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"];


function loop() {
    var len = elements.length;
    
    len = len/2;
    var str = "";
    for(var i = len ; i< elements.length; i++){
       str += " "+elements[i];
    }
    
    for(var i = 0 ; i< len ; i++){
             str += " "+ elements[i];
    }
    
   document.getElementById('loopedRow').innerHTML = str;

}


loop();
```

```html
<div id="loopedRow"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know how to explain this... I mean I want to have only one time looped over array but graphically looped row like on the example screenshot I've provided.

Comment: Not much, sorry :x As I mentioned in the question this row should work as a carousel so it can't be string, each element should be separate, I don't know what to use yet but I think as a spans would be ok ex. <div id="loopedRow"><span>One</span><span>Two</span><span>Three</span><span>Four</span><span>Five</span><span>Six</span><span>Seven</span><span>Eight</span><span>Nine</span><span>Ten</span></div>